# Warning/error message after closing blender file

Tags: add-on

I am using Blender 3.0.1. When I close the blender files, the message below appear. I cannot close this message but have to click Blender icon and select close window. May I know what's happen? Would it have harmful effect on my blender program and Blender files? Would somebody advise me how to fix them?

Thank you

Lightman Leaf[image]

Comment: Well, if you read the messages, there seems to be an error with the Interior Essentials installation directory. Maybe try disabling Interior Essentials or re-install it?

Comment: Sorry to border you again, do you mean I should reinstall blender 3.0.1?

Comment: No, this Interior Essentials thing whatever it is... or throw it out if you don't need it.

Comment: The primary error is "The custom presets directory seems invalid" and the message specifies the directory name: `C:\\Remap Presets/`  Notice that that ends with a forward slash, which would make it invalid on a Windows system.  It might be an artifact of the way the error message is written, but more likely it's a problem with the add-on's presets.  You probably need to open the add-on in Preferences and fix that spelling.  If it's not that it's that `C:\\Remap Presets` in fact doesn't exist.